# error C3481: 'Out': lambda capture variable not found while calling ObjectIDGenerator.GetID in C++/CLI

Tags: lambda, c++-cli, boolean, out, objectid

I need to pass a boolean value in the ObjectIDGenerator.GetID(Object^,out bool) in C++/CLI.
 Having a similar problem as described here.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/2ec8e666-ecac-491e-bfb1-1b9108f7eb92
Searched over the net for this class.. New to this error and to the concept of Lambda. So read [THIS](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)
Still getting the above error..What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First rule of SO: show the code that's giving you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass an lvalue of type `bool`:

```
ObjectIDGenerator ^generator;
Object ^o;
bool isFirst;
generator->GetID(o, isFirst);
```

There are no lambdas involved.  The reason for your error is that you must have stuck `[Out]` somewhere in your code, which looked to the compiler like a lambda.  But `[Out]` is never used when calling a function.